How to check in MapBasic if a Ribbon Control exist
I have a MapBasic application running fine on old MapInfo. Now, I like to migrate it to new RibbonUI 64-bit MapInfo - without re-inventing the wheel.
In old tool it looked like this:
Define BP_NETSITE 18

Create ButtonPad "DPImap" As
   ToggleButton
     Icon MI_ICON_REALESTATE_1
     HelpMsg "NETsite Sites\nNETsite Sites"
     Calling MVectorChange
     Id BP_NETSITE
     Enable

Sub MVectorChange()
Dim ButtonID As Integer
    ButtonId = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_TOOLBTN)

    If ButtonId = BP_NETSITE Then
        Print "Start NETsite.."
    End If

End Sub

Now, in RibbonUI the Id property does not exist anymore (at least I did not find it). My new version looks like this:
Create Ribbon Tab "DPImap" 
    Caption "DPImap" 
    Enable 
    Group "DPI_Layers" 
        Caption "Layers" Show Enable 
        ToolTip "Show more Layers"
        Controls(
            Control "DPI_" + BP_NETSITE
                Type CTRL_TYPE_BUTTON ToggleButton Uncheck 
                Size Small Caption "NETsite" Show Enable 
                ToolTip "Open sites Layer from NETsite" 
                SmallIcon Id MI_ICON_REALESTATE_1
                Calling MVectorChange
        )


Function ButtonIdFromRibbon() as Integer
    ButtonIdFromRibbon = -1
    If RibbonInfo("DPI_" + BP_NETSITE, PROPERTY_ISSELECTED) Then
        ButtonIdFromRibbon = BP_NETSITE
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function


Sub MVectorChange()
Dim ButtonID As Integer

    If SystemInfo(SYS_INFO_MAPINFO_INTERFACE) = MIINTERFACE_RIBBON Then
        ButtonId = ButtonIdFromRibbon()
    Else
        ButtonId = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_TOOLBTN)
    End If
    If ButtonId = -1 Then
        'No ToggleButton is selected
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If ButtonId = BP_NETSITE Then
        Print "Start Sub NETsite.."
    End If

End Sub

This works fine for a single Ribbon control but I like to have it more dynamic. Is there a function to check whether a Ribbon control exist? Or is there a function which returns a list of all available Ribbon controls where I can loop over?
If I run RibbonInfo("not_existing", PROPERTY_ISSELECTED) then I message box "A Ribbon Tab, Group, or Control, with name or index 'not_existing' cannot be found for the specified ribbon.", however I prefer a solution without OnError Goto ...

My code does not work properly, because it does not tell me which Toggle-Button was unchecked.
But I found the solution.

CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_TOOLBTN) returns the ID of the button the user clicked

Corresponding property for Ribbon are

CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_NAME)) Returns the Name Property of the Ribbon Control.
CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_FULLNAME)) Returns the full path to the Control in the Ribbon

